# function ${\displaystyle \varphi }$ such that ${\displaystyle \varphi (\varphi (u))=\exp(u)}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, chain-rule, holomorphic-functions, tetration

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfunction#History) it's cited:

> the existence of the holomorphic function ${\displaystyle \varphi }$  such that ${\displaystyle \varphi (\varphi (u))=\exp(u)}$ had been demonstrated in 1950 by Hellmuth Kneser.

However I can't find the definition of the function $\varphi(u)$ anywhere.

Does this function truly exist? And if so, What *is* the function?

Comment: Yes, it exists, since its existence has been proven by Kneser. Are you asking instead if we know it *explicitly*  (constructive proof), or if the proof of its existence is non-constructive?

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry should have been more clear, I'm wondering what the function actually is defined as. Or if it only exists abstractly.

Comment: Your link says [ H.Kneser (1950). "Reelle analytische L¨osungen der Gleichung {\displaystyle \varphi (\varphi (x))=e^{x}} \varphi(\varphi(x)) = e^x  und verwandter Funktionalgleichungen". Journal fur die reine und angewandte Mathematik. 187: 56–67.], so you only need to find the paper.

Comment: I guess the main question then is: *do you speak German?* (to read the original article), or *do you speak French?* (to read the [review on MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0035385)).

Comment: In the latter, it is written " The solutions of the functional equation $\varphi\circ \varphi =f$, where $f$ is given and $\varphi$ is the unknown function, is of the form $$\varphi(x) = \psi^{-1}\!\left(\psi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\beta\right)$$ where $\psi$ is a solution of the [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation) $\psi(f(x)) = \psi(x)+\beta$ where $f$ and $\beta$ are given; the inverse function $\psi^{-1}$ needing to be suitably defined. [...]"

Comment: There is a thorough discussion on MathOverflow: [f(f(x))=exp(x)-1 and other functions “just in the middle” between linear and exponential](https://mathoverflow.net/q/4347)